# HTML form missing inputs (PHP)

Tags: php, html

On one of my clients server, I created a form that may have up to 800 input fields. But upon submission all input after the 200th one are missing. I've checked for the max_input_vars and it's set to 1000. While max_execution_time and max_input_time are set to 60. I've created a test file you can find here, **url deleted** which creates 1000 input fields and upon submission print the POST data. Form is OK but this one also displays input #0 to input #199 as the POST data after submission.

There are no chances for,

- error with url encoding as input are simple integers
- error with naming as it's a single array

php Info is available here: **url deleted**

Code for the test file(test.php):

```
<?php
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
        var_dump($_POST);
    }     

?>

<form action="" method="post">
<?php
    for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++) {
        echo "<input name='in[]' type='text' value='$i' />";
    }
?>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try increasing post_max_vars

Comment: Update PHP if possible, at least to 5.3.15

Comment: Firebug tells me the whole enchilada was posted, so it's definitely a problem with how PHP is processing the form.

Comment: have you tried print_r($_POST); instead of var_dump?

Comment: agreed with @BogdanBurim -- upgrade PHP as soon as you can -- 5.2 was declared 'end-of-life' more than two years ago; it's badly out of date and missing a lot of functionality that is available in newer versions. (and even more importantly, it isn't getting any security fixes! if you're on 5.2 your site is vulnerable to attack).

Comment: by the way, I'm sure you have your reasons, but why on earth would you want to have a form with 800 fields? There's got to be some usability issues there, regardless of any actual PHP or browser issues with doing it. Couldn't you divide them into pages?

Comment: @Spudley It's surprisingly easy to get to that number when your "client" basically wants "Excel" within their app. I had to fix something that had ~12 inputs per row, and they liked entering a 100 rows or more at a time, sometimes. And yes, the UX was terrible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following settings in your php.ini:

`suhosin.post.max_vars  200 200`

`suhosin.request.max_vars   200 200`

[Suhosin is an advanced protection system for PHP installations.](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/)

Changing these can be done by executing this somewhere in your application:

`ini_set('suhosin.request.max_vars', 1000)`

`ini_set('suhosin.post.max_vars', 1000)`

Comment: Please add some context, otherwise this isn't an answer at all.

Comment: It clearly is *the* answer to his problem, but I added some context for future reference.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to configure suhosin.post.max_vars/suhosin.request.max_vars if I don't have access to php.ini?

Comment: @MuhammedHedayet: yes, you can probably configure them at runtime by using `ini_set('suhosin.post.max_vars', 1000)`.

Comment: I've added these two lines on top of my code

    ini_set('suhosin.post.max_vars', 1000);
    ini_set('suhosin.request.max_vars', 1000);

still it's missing data. I believe the issue is with suhosin as you pointed but am trying to find a way to bypass these values as I don't have access to php.ini

Comment: If ini_set doesn't work I'd contact the host and ask if they can change it for you. Shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Another solution is using Javascript to generate JSON from it.

Answer (score -2):

check post_max_size in your php.ini file and try increasing it

if you don't have access to the php.ini, try `ini_set("post_max_size", "100M");` by default it's 8MB